# Adding objects to ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I have the following Java classes and relationships:
[image]

A property has an address and a viewing arrangement.
An address has a street number, street name, suburb and a 4-digit postcode (in the range 6000 to 6999).
A viewing arrangement has a contact person and an open time during the week.
A contact person has a name, office (eg, Murdoch, Kardinya, Applecross, Fremantle, ...) and phone number.
A for-sale property is a property with a selling arrangement.
A selling arrangement could be an offered price or an auction date.
A rental property is a property with a rental amount and a vacancy date.
A property manager manages a list of properties.

My doubts are:
1. Should I use different ArrayLists for Property,address,ViewingArrangement,ContactPerson,Market?
Or Is there anyway to achieve this?
2. If can, Is it must to create all the ArrayLists in the main program only? Like following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PropertyMain {

    public static void main (String[] argv){
        ArrayList<Property> plist = new ArrayList<Property>();
        plist.add(new Property(address, view));
        plist.add(new SaleProperty(address, view, 0, '10-6-2016'));

        ArrayList<Address> addr_list = new ArrayList<Address>();
        addr_list.add(new Address("woodlands", 4, "woodlands", 34));

        ArrayList<ViewingArrangement> view_list = new ArrayList<ViewingArrangement>();


        ArrayList<ContactPerson> person_list = new ArrayList<ContactPerson>();



//        ArrayList<Market> market_list = new ArrayList<Market>();

    }

}
```

Am very much stuck here.. Much appreciated if any of the kind helps and guides. Please don't downgrade if the question looks very silly, am very new to Java that's why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your questions depends entirely on what your program is supposed to do.  You haven't told us that.

Comment: I can not event understand your handwriting...

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa All the writing in the diagram is repeated in the text below it.

Comment: I can not even understand your typewriting.

Comment: My program should able to do the following David:

Comment: a) construct a list of 6 different properties with made-up details built in to the program;
b) change the open time of one property;
c) change the contact person of one property;
d) remove one property from the market;
e) add one property to the market;
f) list all the properties for rent in a suburb, e.g. Murdoch.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to revolve around properties, so you will almost certainly want a list of `Property` instances.  As to whether to have lists of the other various objects, it's up to you, but it's probably unnecessary.

Whatever lists of objects you **do** opt to create, you'll probably want them to be class-level or instance-level members of `PropertyMain`, not local to the `main` method, so that other methods you create can get at them easily.